# How to solve terminal window

Tags: terminal

[image]

I am getting the following error:

- There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
- Failed to execute child process "terminal" (No such file or directory)

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: The text in the image is tiny. Please paste the error message into your question. Not only will that make it more readable, but it will make it more searchable (for the benefit of future visitors).

Comment: "Failed to execute child process 'terminal' (No such file or directory)" You put "terminal" somewhere, right?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you entered `terminal` in the configuration in the place where you should write the program name that should run **inside** the terminal window.

Normally, that is a input field below the name ot the terminal profile you are editing.

`/bin/bash` would be good, if you want to use `bash` normally.

You can leave it empty, then a default is choosen - which is probably `bash` too.